# Insert via EntityFramework erro de "IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

Tenho várias *models* e por algum motivo uma delas apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tbl_boleto' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Lembro que já cheguei a inserir um registro, mas agora não consigo mais.

```
    var NewBoleto = new Boleto
    {
        ClienteId = 3,
        DataVencimento = DateTime.Today,
        Valor = 4,
        DataBaixa=null,
        DataEmissao = DateTime.Now,
        DataReferencia= DateTime.Today,
        DataPagamento = null
    };

   db.Boletos.Add(NewBoleto);
   db.SaveChanges();
```

A model:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace WMB.Models
{
    [Table("tbl_boleto")]
    public class Boleto
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("int_ID")]
        public int BoletoId { get; set; }

        [Column("int_IDC")]
        public int ClienteId { get; set; }

        [Column("sdt_Dataemissao")]
        public DateTime DataEmissao { get; set; }

        [Column("sdt_DataVencimento")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Data de Vencimento é requerida")]
        [Display(Name = "Data de Vencimento")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DataVencimento { get; set; }


        [Column("sdt_dataPagamento")]
        public DateTime? DataPagamento { get; set; }


        [Column("sdt_dataBaixa")]
        public DateTime? DataBaixa { get; set; }

        [Column("sdt_DataReferencia")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        [Display(Name = "Referência 01/mm/aaaa")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DataReferencia { get; set; }

        [Column("cur_valor")]
        public decimal? Valor { get; set; }

        [Column("cur_valorPago")]
        public decimal? ValorPago { get; set; }

        [Column("int_status")]
        public byte Status { get; set; }

        [Column("int_TotalMeses")]
        public byte? TotalMeses { get; set; }

        [Column("int_Tipo")]
        public byte Tipo { get; set; }

        [Column("int_ViewClient")]
        public byte? QtdVisualizacoes { get; set; }


        public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("BoletoId")]
        //public virtual BoletoTXT boletoTxt { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Ao olhar pelo SQL profile por algum motivo desconhecido para essa model ele está enviando o campo PK que é autonumerável. (int_ID)
Para todas as outras model está funcionando.

**Atualização**:
**Descobri o motivo do erro, mas não sei o porquê.**
Tenho uma outra Model que se chama BoletoTXT que tem ligação com a Boleto
N-1

```
 [Table("tbl_boleto_TXT")]
    public class BoletoTXT
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("int_ID")]
        public int BoletoTXTId { get; set; }

        [Column("int_IDBoleto")]
        public int BoletoId { get; set; }

        [Column("str_Mensagem")]
        public string Menssagem { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BoletoId")]
        public virtual ICollection<boleto> boleto { get; set; }

    }
```

O problema é essa linha

```
[ForeignKey("BoletoId")]
public virtual ICollection<boleto> boleto { get; set; }
```

Mas já usei assim em outros projetos e não lembro de ter dado erro.
Estou fazendo a relação errada?

Comment: Por acaso você gerou o seu model através do Database First? Se estiver usando [Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) poste como está a configuração.

Comment: Pode tentar adicionar a annotation `[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` na PK

Comment: Provavelmente sua tabela foi alterada após você ter gerado seu modelo..

Comment: Se o banco de dados for sql server tente exec                                                       **SET IDENTITY_INSERT to ON.** 
`SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_boleto ON;
GO`

Comment: Remove o ClienteId antes de dar o add e tenta novamente.

Comment: Filipe o ClienteId eu preciso enviar, oq não poderia enviar seria o BoletoId.
@Marconcilio Souza, pior que não ouve mudança.

Comment: Se você passa o BoletoId  ele gravar?

Comment: Seu banco é sql server:?

Comment: MS SQL server, em teoria para fazer um insert não deve enviar o BoletoId que é a key (pk) porém até tentei e não grava..mesmo erro

Comment: Porque você renomeia o nome da suas colunas? Ja tentou só  `[Key]
         public int int_ID{ get; set; `

Comment: fiz uma atualização na pergunta @Marconcilio Souza

Comment: [ForeignKey("int_ID")] ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o problema foi a forma de criar as relações entre boletos e boletoTXT

como tinha sido feito boletoTXT tinha vários boletos, por isso ele fazia o uso da chave estrangeira.

Na model Boletos
ficou

```
public virtual ICollection<BoletoTXT> BoletoTXT { get; set; }
```

e na model BoletosTXT

```
public virtual boleto Boleto { get; set; }
```

**e tudo resolve-se**